# Setting Python version on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x

I had installed python 3.9.0 back in October. This week I was trying to install Rasa but the installation failed with the following message

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow<2.2,>=2.1 (from rasa) (from versions: none)

This is because Rasa requires 3.6 or 3.7. I installed 3.7.8 using pyenv but when I check
/usr/local/bin, I don't see 3.7.8 listed. How can I set 3.7.8 as the default python3 version

[usr/local/bin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMLBE.png)

Comment: if  you are  using pyenv you can use  pyenv global python_version  to set  the python version  as  default  python. To get  the pythons installed use the command pyenv versions

Comment: Why don't you install [Conda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) on Mac and install all the dependencies using **Conda** until the support is provided - There is [no support](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/7473) as of yet for **Python 3.9.0** in **Rasa**.